# Save the state of a form with PictureBox?

Tags: c#, image, state, picturebox

I have a small program in winforms; it's just a program where I can have pictures, but I have a problem. When I have a picture, I close the program and I open it again, the pictures don't stay where I have put them, in the PictureBox.

More simply, I want to keep the state when I close the program, like saving.

Here my code :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog f = new OpenFileDialog();
            f.ShowDialog();


            var chemin = f.FileName;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = chemin;

        }

    }
}
```

Please help me, I can't go on with this problem...

Comment: You should read about serialization, you need to save the data in a file, then read it back when the program starts
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656718.aspx

Comment: ...or just save the filename location to settings

Comment: Plutonix: With what can i do this ?

Comment: Can you give me an example because i really don't understand serialization :(

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use the Application Settings.  Right-click on your Project and select Properties.  Then go to Settings.  In the right hand side, you will see a panel with a grid with only one line.  Change Setting in the Name column to ImageLocation and leave the other three values (Type, Scope and Value) as their defaults (string, user and blank).

In design view of your form under properties double-click the FormClosing event to create a new handler.  Now enter:

```
        if (pictureBox1.ImageLocation != null)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.ImageLocation = pictureBox1.ImageLocation;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

Finally in the constructor for the form enter the following after InitializeComponent():

```
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.ImageLocation != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = Properties.Settings.Default.ImageLocation;
        }
```

HTH